# record not fetching from database in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

I am using this command it is not fetching record.
my command

```
select * from policy_record_manual where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), enddate, 103) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '25/02/2015', 103) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '04/03/2015', 103))
```

I have two records in `enddate` column which lies between `25/02/2015` and `04/03/2015` but still not fetching any result.
please help

Comment: Instead of between use > 24/02/2015  and < 05/03/2015 and convert both sides in same format. Use Varchar(10)

Comment: Which ***database system*** is this for??

Comment: Don't convert dates to strings in queries.

Comment: so how i can insert date in SQL database???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proper date formats and your query should work:

```
select *
from policy_record_manual
where enddate between '2015-02-05' and '2015-03-04'
```

You are doing the comparison as strings.  Don't compare date/times as strings.  Compare them using the native types.

You should always compare dates/datetimes with dates - and not strings.  Most databases -- including SQL Server -- support the ISO standard for dates and recognize strings in that format.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server, you can change the date format in the query by using [SET DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) statement.

```
set dateformat dmy
declare @begin datetime='25/02/2015'
declare @end datetime='04/03/2015'

select *
from policy_record_manual
where enddate between @begin and @end
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select * 
from policy_record_manual
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), enddate, 103) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '02/25/2015', 103) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '03/04/2015', 103))
```